# Could not locate the 'cplex' executable, which is required for solver cplex

Tags: python, cplex

The solver has been installed, but an error is reported when building a model with `pyomo`,

```
opt = SolverFactory('cplex')



results = opt.solve(instance,symbolic_solver_labels=True,tee=True)
```

The previous solver was `Gurobi`, which I didn't have on my computer yet, so I changed it to `CPLEX`